# Run Scrapy Spiders sequential

Tags: python, scrapy

I have several Scrapy spiders inside my spiders' directory ( let's suppose 50 spiders), now I want to run them sequential (not concurrent)

I could run them concurrent with the following code but because of some policy I've decided to run them sequentially ,

```
start=datetime.now()
setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)
for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    print(spider_name)
    process.crawl(spider_name) #query dvh is custom argument used in your scrapy

process.start()
print("***********Execution time : {0}".format((datetime.now()-start)))
```

Also, I tried

```
for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
   print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
   os.system("pwd ")
   os.system("pwd && scrapy crawl " + spider_name) //pwd to make sure it's in correct path and I see it is
```

but it seems cant run by `os.system`, another solution is  using a `.sh` but I'm not sure it's a good idea.
**I'm looking for a solution to run spiders sequentially?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scrapy documentation has a section explaining how to run [multiple spiders in the same process](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.9/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) and also how to do this sequentially.

For your case, this could look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

start = datetime.now()
settings = get_project_settings()
configure_logging(settings)
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    for spider_name in runner.spider_loader.list():
        print("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
        yield runner.crawl(spider_name)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
print("***********Execution time : {0}".format((datetime.now()-start)))
```

This only works if [Spider Loader](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=spider%20loader#spider-loader-class) is properly configured. Otherwise, you can also simple list all your spiders in the crawl method one by one.

Comment: look at the question time, 2017 ;) I fully abandoned python :D

Comment: I saw the year of the post. When I searched for the exact same problem, I stumbled upon this post first without an answer. I figured some people will do as well and therefore posted my answer which I discovered later on.